# My app crashes after I use doInBackground(Object... arg0)

Tags: android

Everything was fine until I used `doInBackground(Object... arg0)` inorder to show `ProgressDialog` until it is loaded then dismisses it on `onPostExecute(Object result)` method. No error message in a `LogCat`, just crashes.  Please help?

Vacancy.java

```
 package com.apps.vacancy;

//all the necessary imports are imported

public class Vacancy extends Activity {

public static String urlPageNumHolder;
public ProgressDialog dialog;

ListView lisView1;
EditText inputText;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vacancy);

    lisView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    // Permission StrictMode
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchJob();
        }
    });

}

public void searchJob() {
    new LoadContentFromServer().execute();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Vacancy", "Loading...", true, false);
}

public String getJSONUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Log", "Failed to download file..");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str.toString();
}

class LoadContentFromServer extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

        String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/smartaddis/mobile/vacancy/getVacancy.php";

        // Paste Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtKeyword", inputText.getText().toString()));

        try {
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url, params));

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("id", c.getString("id"));
                map.put("title_en", c.getString("title_en"));
                map.put("description_en", c.getString("description_en"));
                map.put("posteddate", c.getString("posteddate"));
                map.put("expiredate", c.getString("expiredate"));
                MyArrList.add(map);

            }

            lisView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView,
                        int position, long mylng) {

                    urlPageNumHolder = MyArrList.get(position).get("id").toString();

                    Intent subActivity = new Intent(Vacancy.this,
                            VacancyWebber.class);

                    Bundle translateBundle = ActivityOptions
                            .makeCustomAnimation(Vacancy.this,
                                    R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left).toBundle();
                    startActivity(subActivity, translateBundle);
                }
            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return MyArrList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        if (dialog != null)
            dialog.dismiss();

        SimpleAdapter sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(Vacancy.this, result,
                R.layout.vacancy_column, new String[] { "title_en",
                        "description_en", "posteddate", "expiredate" }, new int[] { R.id.jobtitle,
                        R.id.jobdescription, R.id.jobdateTime, R.id.jobexpiredate });

        lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);
    }

}

@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

}

Comment: there is no such thing as "just crash". You are accessing the ui from your doinbg, `lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);`. this is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You are updating ui from `doInbackground` which you should not do. Return the result in `doInbackground` and update ui in `onPostExecute`.

In `doInbackground` return `MyArrList`. The result of background computation is a passed to `onPostExecute`.

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Object... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            ... // rest of the code
    return MyArrList;
}
```

In `onPostExecute` initialize adapter and set the adapter to listview.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
            //  dimiss dialog
            SimpleAdapter sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(Vacancy.this, result,
                    R.layout.vacancy_column, new String[] { "title_en",
                            "description_en", "posteddate", "expiredate" }, new int[] { R.id.jobtitle,
                            R.id.jobdescription, R.id.jobdateTime, R.id.jobexpiredate });

            lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);
            ... // rest of the code
}
```

For more info

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You also need to move the below inside `onCreate` after `setContentView` coz `findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout.

```
ListView lisView1;
EditText inputText;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.vacancy);
lisView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Comment: Check the code I updated it. But now it gives me two errors: first, it says `can't return MyArrList` and second it says `remove @Override from onPostExecute (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result)`

Comment: @EthioDroid check here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I checked it, but it's kinda hard for me, 'cos, I'm a newbie. What about: `can't return MyArrList`

Comment: why can't you return MyArrList?. You can an it should work do you get any exceptions or errors and it will be hard so pls check the docs and try to  understand what is there and then try my suggestion